# finding fonts to write quran verses on android

Tags: fonts

I need to write an application that contains some quranic verses so I need a quran font where can i find one? such as http://zekr.org/wiki/Image:Quran-KFGQPC_Uthman_Taha_Naskh.png

where the {} and () are symbolised with a new form please can anyone tell me where can I find such a font for android?

Comment: If you are looking for fonts, then Google does provide links, ex. ( http://freearabicfonts.com/Free_Arabic_Fonts ). As for how to implement it, I haven't personally gotten the chance to do so. Finally, if you are planning to make a Quran app, I wouldn't expect it to get much publicity (if that is what you are aiming), the market is dominated by "Quran Android". Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your font with 'Fontlab' Software and save it in binary mode.

Comment: @LuckyMe : thanks for the help and no that's not what I am doing...

Comment: please does anybody know where can I find such fonts..